# I am writing a code to get rid of the last vowel in a word, but it is deleting the last letter. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code to get rid of the last vowel in a word, but it is deleting the last letter. Where am I going wrong?

```
 function removeLastVowel(word) {
      var vowels = ["a", 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
      for (var i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(word[i]) !== undefined) {
          return (word.slice(0, i) + word.slice(i + 1));
          }
        }
      return word;
    }

console.log(removeLastVowel("heard"));
```

Comment: try `vowels.indexOf(word[i]) !== -1` !

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf()` returns -1 if not found, not undefined

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is already an answer to this question,
but I found it interesting to solve this problem with regex.

this might look hacky, but it works ;)

This regex just says:
**Take one of these *[aeiou]* if after there are none of these *[aeiou]*. It took me a bit to understand this.**

```js
function removeLastVowel(word) {
  return word.replace(/[aeiou](?!.*?[aeiou])/i, '')
}

console.log(removeLastVowel("ax"));
console.log(removeLastVowel("aa"));
console.log(removeLastVowel("hearaa"));
console.log(removeLastVowel("heara"));
console.log(removeLastVowel("hea"));
```